# Возможно ли получить доступ к контактам пользователя с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript

Может кто то задавался таким вопросом. Можно ли при согласии самого пользователя, когда он зашел на сайт с телефона, вытянуть его контакты с телефонной книги? Спасибо за ответ. А и еще, возможно ли это в принцыпе, с помощью js к ним добраться?

Comment: Не, с помощью JS на сайте невозможно обратиться к командам операционки, даже к запросу разрешения на действия, иначе это была бы дыра. JS даже не позволяет обращаться к файлам на компьютере.

Comment: @Komdosh спасибо за пояснение.